# Given a wparam, how can I determine if that is the File->Exit command in an MFC app?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc

Is there a defined constant somewhere in MFC that is the standard define for the File->Exit menu command? I'm trying to determine if a command is that one, but I've only got a WPARAM to work with.

Comment: If you have wParam, you have a message. Which message is it? WM_QUIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APP_EXIT (57665 or 0xE141) is sent on command to the message map declared in appcore.cpp (or if you override it in your CWinApp derived class);

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWinApp, CCmdTarget)
  ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_EXIT, &CWinApp::OnAppExit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

In turn, OnAppExit sends a WM_CLOSE message to the main window in CWinApp:

```
void CWinApp::OnAppExit()
{
  // same as double-clicking on main window close box
  ASSERT(m_pMainWnd != NULL);
  m_pMainWnd->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
}
```

That's how your application ends in MFC, no WM_QUIT.